# QWebEngineView and Ember.js ES6

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, ember.js

Before I begin, I know almost nothing about JavaScript. I'm just a lowly C++ developer being tasked to do something that *should* be easy.

In essence, I need to configure a QWebEngineView to show a webpage that is being developed for us by an outside UI vendor.  Whenever I load the page in my QWebEngineView, I get a ton of errors in the JavaScript Console (https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRcmK.jpg).  However, if I go to the page directly through Chrome, everything looks exactly like it should (https://i.stack.imgur.com/og3bf.jpg).

I have checked that other webpages can load correctly within my view, but, for whatever reason, not the page that is being developed for us.  I have also scoured the Qt documentation for references to any JavaScripts limitations and have also found none.

For reference, they are using Ember.js with JavaScript version ES6 and I am using the latest version 5.5.1 of the Qt framework, but have also tried 5.3.2. I have also tried using the now deprecated QtWebKit instead of QtWebEngine hoping it was simply a design oversight in the new widget.

Any help either solving this issue or coming up with a strategy to figure out how to debug this would be amazing!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you loading from files/embedded resources or from a web site?

Comment: I am going directly to a website.  The vendor provided us with a URL that we can navigate to to preview their work.